# Excel Q: How do I get the sum of each category for each person?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to collate the total numbers for each type of document that students send to me:

Example document:

[image]

For example, for "PK" (in the second table,) I need to calculate the total number of "Journal," "Miscellaneous Review," and so on. Is there any formula that will help me do this?

Edit:

[Sample doc 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AT8F.jpg)

Comment: Please include the image in the question itself. As it stands, the question is rather incrompehensible without clicking the link, making it a delete-candidate

Comment: I would have loved to do that but since I am a new user of the site, Stackoverflow does not allow images within the question. I can only upload it as a link.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very easy SUMIFS problem.

Using your sheet, the code should be:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,N$2,$D:$D,$M3)
```

Just copy and paste for all the cells you need.

For future reference, you should really show any efforts you have tried previously

Comment: Clauric: Thank you. I am very new to Excel formulas. I tried various solutions, which didn't work, before I decided to ask here. Your solution didn't work either. I copied and pasted the code first into cell N3 to check if it works, but it just returns the value 0. All other cells return 0 as well

Comment: Just checked the code. It seems to work for me. For the code to work, the names in column B and the names in row 2, from M - V must be the exact same, with no differences, including spaces, capitalisation, etc.

Comment: I found that I had missed to include 'Synopsis/Pre-synopsis' as a column in the second table and inserted it at R2. However, the code now wrongly returns the value of certain cells as 0 but calculates others correctly.

Comment: Since I am still not allowed to embed images, I have edited my original question to add a link of an image of the document with the code inserted. I have highlighted the errors in blue.

Comment: @ShebaS I still think that the issue is around your names, either the names of the docs or the names of the people. I suggest that you check them all for trailing " ".